# mysql: mysql locate everything left of

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to mysql and your assistance would be much appreciated.
I am trying to locate everything left of a url parameter in my 'url' column.

The URI in the 'url' columns contain a query parameter '?'.  I would like to remove everything right of '?' and update the column with everything left of '?'.  The URIs look like the follwing:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/team-sports/football/4125_4161_434036?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L277
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/sports-outdoors/golf/4125_4152?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L278
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/team-sports/volleyball/4125_4161_1041862/?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L282
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/christmas-decor/holiday-lighting/2637_633379_1025279
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/christmas-decor/holiday-lighting/2637_633379_1025279/?povid=P1171-C1093.2766-L109
```

I'm able to find everything left of the character '?' using the code, but I can't figure out how to update the column url column with the information:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '\?', 1) AS url
From mytable
```

thank you for your time, much appreacted!

Comment: UPDATE MyTable set `newUrl` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`url`, '\?', 1) where SomeCondition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` statement, not `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET url = SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '?', 1)
```

There's no need to escape the `?` character.